# I am getting the "end if block without if" error in the below code

Tags: vba

I am getting the "end if block without if" error in the below code:

```
Sub test()
    Dim Total As Double
    Dim Timein As Date
    Dim Timeout As Date
    a = 2
    b = 0
label2: a = 2
   For a = 2 To 21
   b = a + 1
      If a >= 20 Then GoTo label2
         Timein = CDate(Cells(a, 1).Value)
         Timeout = CDate(Cells(b, 1).Value)
         Total = TimeValue(Timeout) - TimeValue(Timein)
         Debug.Print Total
         Debug.Print Format(Total, "hh:mm:ss")
         Cells(a, 4).NumberFormat = "hh:mm:ss"
         Cells(a, 4).Value = Total
         Debug.Print "Number of hours = " & Total * 24
      
      End If
   Next a
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do `End If` only if you have done `If … Then`. 
`If … Then GoTo` stands by itself, and should not be matched with an `End If`.

Comment: This. And you can easily test this with a `'` at the start of the `End If` line.

Comment: *If … Then GoTo stands by itself, and should not be matched with an End If.* Not because of Goto, but because the action is posessed in the same line. Put GoTo on the next line - and you need in End If.

Comment: @Akina: Thanks for rattling my cage and reminding me of what I should have known.  I was just recently looking at `On Error`, where `On Error Resume Next` and `On Error Goto …` are considered to be significantly, fundamentally different, and that clouded my head when I wrote this answer.